# findOneAndUpdate if not save new item is not working (Mongoose, Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to send some objects to database utilizing Mongoose.
Namely, I get search queries and save them to db, keeping record on unique entries count.

Here's my schema:

```
const entrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    searchWord: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    numEntries:{type:Number,default:0},
  });

  const entry = module.exports = mongoose.model('entry', entrySchema);
```

Here's the method that i use:

```
searchRouter.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    let entry = new SearchEntry();

    SearchEntry.findOneAndUpdate({ searchWord: req.body.searchWord },
        { $inc: { numEntries: 1 } },
        { new: true }, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (!response.length) {
                entry.searchWord = req.body.searchWord;
                SearchEntry.save((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
});
```

Now in console it spits out an error when I try to test it with postman:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Any ideas on what do I do wrong?

P.S. the REST client responds "The requested URL can't be reached",
however we hit the desired route and post method is being launched.

Comment: try -> `if (response && !response.length) { ... }`

Comment: The REST Client stucks in this case

Comment: Because you're never sending back a response.

Comment: I like the idea, but what do you mean? Where should I send it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response could be null not an empty string, object or an array of object, and you can't get a null length because null is not a string or an array of object, so you must check if the response != null, then test the length.

Answer (score 0):

With a help of yours finally got to the solution:

searchRouter.post('/search', (req, res) => {

```
let entry = new SearchEntry();

SearchEntry.findOneAndUpdate({ searchWord: req.body.searchWord },
    { $inc: { numEntries: 1 } },
    { new: true }, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('find error ', err);
        }
        if (response === null) {
            console.log('here');
            entry.searchWord = req.body.searchWord;
            console.log(entry);

            entry.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('save error', err);
                }
            })
        }
    })

    res.send('done');
```

});